# CSS Selection property

Tags: html, css

Assume that the evergreen, fruit, and leaf classes are not used elsewhere on the page. What selector will select the apple tree, but none of the others?

```
<ul id="forest">
 <li class="evergreen"><a>pine</a></li>
 <li class="evergreen"><a>lodgepole</a></li>
 <li class="evergreen fruit"><a>holly</a></li>
 <li class="leaf fruit"><a>apple</a></li>
 <li class="leaf"><a>oak</a></li>
 <li class="leaf"><a>maple</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `#forest .leaf.fruit`?

Comment: Would there be another `class="leaf fruit"`?

Comment: What you tried so far? please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and be welcome to SO

Comment: Another question, would the order of the `<li>` changes?

Comment: Is this some kind of homework assignment?

Comment: yes, it's homework assignent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the apple tree like this:

```
#forest .leaf.fruit {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

But maybe you could use more specific classnames

Answer (score 1):

## For selecting with CSS:

```
.leaf.fruit{
  background-color:red;
}
```

Safe way is to refer the `ul` as well: `#forest > .leaf.fruit{`

This only works in this case as you have no element with has both the `leaf` and `fruit` class assigned

## Other option with CSS:

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/1520501/9167318

If you update your markup to:
`<li class="leaf fruit" fruit='apple'><a>apple</a></li>`

For selecting the node with the text `apple`, you could use:

```
li[fruit*='apple']{
  background-color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do:

```css
li[class="leaf fruit"] {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<ul id="forest">
 <li class="evergreen"><a>pine</a></li>
 <li class="evergreen"><a>lodgepole</a></li>
 <li class="evergreen fruit"><a>holly</a></li>
 <li class="leaf fruit"><a>apple</a></li>
 <li class="leaf"><a>oak</a></li>
 <li class="leaf"><a>maple</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why use a `class` attribute selector if you can just use `li.leaf.fruit`

Answer (score 0):

Alternate solution

```
li:not(.evergreen).fruit
```

Answer (score 0):

.leaf.fruit

It is the answer to the edx css selectors it is the right answer

Answer (score -1):

```
ul#forest li.leaf.fruit a{
   color: red;
}
```

Comment: please check other ansers first and consider adding some text, that explains your solution